# Heroku deploy fails with Java Dropwizard project using Gradle

Tags: java, heroku, gradle, dropwizard

Heroku deploy fails with Java Dropwizard project using Gradle.

Build https://travis-ci.org/damorton/dropwizardheroku-event-service/builds/228152195

Repo https://github.com/damorton/dropwizardheroku-event-service

**Attempted so far**

- `build.gradle` file in root of repo
- gradle wrapper files in `gradle/` directory
- `./gradlew stage` builds OK
- `heroku local` runs OK
- Travis CI build successfully deploy application using Maven
- Pushing directly to heroku master results in the same failure message shown in the travis build

Comment: When I run `git clone git@github.com:damorton/dropwizardheroku-event-service.git`, and `git push heroku master` it works. Do you know if Travis is pushing the correct branch (`master`)?

Comment: @codefinger yes it was a config issue on the Heroku website. The application was set to use `buildpack/java` because I was using `Maven` originally then switched to `Gradle`. Updating the config to use `buildpack/gradle` on the Heroku.com website worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding an explicit buildpack to your Travis config:

```
deploy:
  provider: heroku
  buildpack: gradle
```

I am able to deploy the Github repo successfully by running `git push heroku master`, so I don't know what the problem is. But the error you see ("Failed to detect app matching no buildpack") indicated that the detection phase of one of the buildpacks failed.

Comment: Specifying `buildpack:gradle` did not work, I also tried creating a new clone of the repo and pushing the application again, this also did not work. You answer however led me to check the application configuration on the Heroku.com website and I noticed that is was set to use the `buildpack/java` config. Removing this and setting it to `buildpack/gradle` resolved the issue. Thanks for your help :)